# How to comparte two metrics, from profile assessment, with different distributions

Tags: distributions, normalization

I have four metrics from an assessment test:

- Energy;
- Emotional Volatility;
- Planning Skills; and
- Creativity.

Each metric has a scale that goes from 1 to 5 (ex: 4.5....1.3)

How can i compare one metric with another if the distribution is different? Like...Energy, a higher value é considered 3.5 or above (90 percentile)....
But in Planning Skills, if you have 1.5 you'll already in the higher group (90 percentile).

How can i get all those metrics to the same base?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The responses below assume that your four scores are measured on an approximately continuous scale.

**Option 1: Quantile transformation**

There is a clue in the wording of your question, part of which I quote below:

> How can i compare one metric with another if the distribution is
>   different? Like...Energy, a higher value é considered 3.5 or above (90
>   percentile).... But in Planning Skills, if you have 1.5 you'll already
>   in the higher group (90 percentile). [sic]

Your mention of percentiles calls to mind that you could transform the data into percentile ranks (or, more generally, [quantile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) ranks) and then compare across metrics using the quantile-transformed values.

One problem with quantile transformation is that you lose information about the original shape of the distribution of the data. In addition, quantiles aren't additive, which limits your ability to form valid aggregations of variables that may be important for comparison purposes.

**Option 2: Standardization and transformation**

Instead of quantile transformation, standardize each variable by subtracting off its mean and then dividing the difference by the standard deviation of that variable (or, even better, dividing the difference by two times the standard deviation as suggested in [this paper](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/standardizing7.pdf). Now your variables all have the same mean and standard deviation, but the shape of their distributions is largely preserved.

Of course, given that your variables all have different distributions, you still have to deal with the fact that some of those distributions may be more skewed than others. This makes it difficult to build a model to assess the correlation structure of your variables, whether through regression or some other means. In this case, you may want to find a suitable transformation of the variables to make them approximately normal *before* standardization.

Then, when you construct your model to compare the different variables, you'll be able to backtransform model output to the original scale by multiplying by the standard deviation (or twice the standard deviation, if that's what you normalized by) and adding the mean before back-transform (e.g., if you decided on a log-transform for a given variable, you would exponentiate the un-standardized figure). If you had instead standardized before transformation, you would reverse the steps described above.